# How do I translate this PostgreSQL regular expression (case insensitive) query into an ILIKE query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, postgresql

I have a query that currently uses PostgresQL...

```
.where("locations.address ~* '#{@street_name}.*#{@street_type}'")
```

In order to prevent special characters being interpreted when this lookup is performed, I need to use an ILIKE query instead.

I'm not sure what this part of the query does and therefore how to translate it

```
.*
```

Can someone help me understand how to translate this query to an ILIKE query without breaking how the current query is constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions `.` means "any character" and `*` means any number of times (including zero). Therefore `.*` means a string containing any characters of any length.

In Postgres, the `%` character in a pattern (used with `(I)LIKE`) means "any string of zero or more characters." ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html))

So just replace the `.*` with `%` when switching from regex matching to pattern matching.

---

Additionally (unrelated to the actual question), it is generally a very bad idea to use string templating to create SQL queries as this method exposes you to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). Instead you should use your ORM's variable functionality. For ActiveRecord, you can pass an array of values to `where`, where the first element is the SQL statement template and the subsequent elements are either variables to insert or a hash of named variables to insert. ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where))

For example:

```
.where(["locations.address ILIKE ? || '%' || ?", street_name, street_type])
```

or

```
.where(["locations.address ILIKE :street_name || '%' || :street_type", {street_name: street_name, street_type: street_type}])
```

Comment: Thanks Henry - in order to use ILIKE instead of ~* will this work: ```.where(["locations.address ILIKE ? || '.*' || ?", street_name, street_type])``` ?

Comment: @BenRichardson If you swap out the `.*` with `%` it should.